# How can I stream a Map of String and Map using java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map<Key1, Map<Key2, CustomObject>>`. I need go through the `Map`, check if `Key2.equals("a string")` and return a `Map<Key1, CustomObject>`.

Is this possible with java 8? Should it be done with java 8 or is it better with nested for loops?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can filter the entries of the input `Map` to keep only entries whose value contains the "a string" key. Then use `Collectors.toMap` to collect them into a new `Map`:

```
Map<Key1, CustomObject> map = 
    inputMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().containsKey("a string"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                      e -> e.getValue().get("a string")));
```

Answer (score 1):

it also works

```
    Map<String, SocialCredentials> collect = configData.getData()
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(map -> map.getValue()
                        .entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(entry -> 
                            profile.toLowerCase().equals(entry.getKey()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> map.getKey(), 
                                                   Map.Entry::getValue)))
                .collect(HashMap::new, Map::putAll, Map::putAll);
```

but your solution is more suitable in my case.

Comment: It works indeed. If you want to avoid Duplicate Key, use : `Collectors.toMap(, , merger)`